# Bitcoin core node not sending outbound connections only inbound traffic

Tags: bitcoin-core

My bitcoin core is not sending outbound connections. It's only getting inbound connections. Iv deleted the whole node then reinstalled it. Still it was only getting inbound connections. Iv checked firewall settings and the node is set to receive inbound and outbound connections. Does anyone know what problem might be? Could I just sync blockchain with only inbound connections?

Comment: I suspect you mean the other way around. What does "getpeerinfo" tell you?

Comment: No I mean it's getting inbound but no outbound connections.

Comment: That's very strange. How did you determine this is the case?

Comment: i clicked on the information tab and looked at the inbound and outbound connections and inbound had 12 connections and inbound showed 0 connections.

Comment: You made a typo there saying "inbound" twice. You may want to clarify.